# Converting an encrypted message to string

Tags: encryption, configparser, pynacl

Here is my encrypted string:

```
b'pN\xe89\xd8\x83x\x9d\ts\xdb\x91\x87\xb4L\x1bU\xf2\x1fQqL\rz\x8d\xbb\xd0J\x99\xb7\xc0\x8a\x17n@\xdc\x16s\xfaf\x17\x00:\x0f\x86'
```

How do I convert this into a String that can be written to `ConfigParser`

later, read this string and convert it back to the correct data type for used for encryption?

```
encrypted username are of type:<class 'nacl.utils.EncryptedMessage'>
```

Comment: There are a number of encodings that can represent binary data (what you have) using a subset of ASCII runes - base64 is probably the most common.

Comment: I tried that encrypted_raw = base64.b64encode(encrypted) and get an error:
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: I think you need to do `b(b'pN\xe89\xd8\x83x\x9d\ts\xdb\x91\x87\xb4L\x1bU\xf2\x1fQqL\rz\x8d\xbb\xd0J\x99\xb7\xc0\x8a\x17n@\xdc\x16s\xfaf\x17\x00:\x0f\x86')` to convert your string to a `bytes` object, can you check? So that's calling the function `b()` on it.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica: at least in python3 literals of the form b'<stuff>' are already `bytes` objects.

Comment: I will try that, and let you know.  Thanks